# Prolog Nodes Path

Tags: prolog

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf0fJ.png)

Write the fact about the above figure and write the following prolog rule: pos_path.

Sample run of the rule:

```
?- pos_path(n1, nx, L). 
L = [n1,n3,n7,nx] ? ; 
L = [n1,n3,n4,n5,nx] ? ; 
L = [n1,n3,n4,n6,nx] ? ; 
no
```

what is the implementation of pos_path ?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to implement pos_path ? and if  we add an extra edge that connects n6 to n3, what will happen to the pos_path ? should it be modified ?

Comment: You can edit your question rather than opening a whole, new question which you seem to have done. Just click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36816002/edit) link under your question.

Comment: You already got an answer, but you are asking again and again!